# Issue with concatenated csv files

Tags: pandas, csv, concatenation

I'm working on a data analytics project for a google course on coursera.  It's a hypothetical ride share company that is working on increasing its profits and wants to come up with a marketing strategy to convert casual riders to full members (annual membership subscription.

my job is to figure out how members and casual riders use the bike share system differently.  I must download and explore the data for the year 2023.  There is a dataset for each month of the year.

I have 12 .csv files (one for each month of 2023) that I must concatenate using pd.concat().  Each file has the same 13 headers. (link to files is below).

link

https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

choose these files when link opens:

202301-divvy-tripdata.zip Feb 7th 2023, 02:58:38 pm 6.78 MB ZIP file

202302-divvy-tripdata.zip Mar 7th 2023, 05:28:12 pm 7.08 MB ZIP file

202303-divvy-tripdata.zip Apr 6th 2023, 04:38:59 pm 10.27 MB ZIP file

202304-divvy-tripdata.zip May 4th 2023, 03:43:25 pm 15.40 MB ZIP file

202305-divvy-tripdata.zip Jun 8th 2023, 06:17:13 pm 23.44 MB ZIP file

202306-divvy-tripdata.zip Jul 13th 2023, 05:22:44 pm 25.66 MB ZIP file

202307-divvy-tripdata.zip Aug 14th 2023, 08:28:28 am 28.54 MB ZIP file

202308-divvy-tripdata.zip Oct 12th 2023, 01:35:18 am 28.65 MB ZIP file

202309-divvy-tripdata.zip Oct 12th 2023, 01:35:18 am 24.89 MB ZIP file

202310-divvy-tripdata.zip Nov 13th 2023, 11:38:10 am 19.15 MB ZIP file

202311-divvy-tripdata.zip Dec 5th 2023, 01:28:19 pm 13.17 MB ZIP file

202312-divvy-tripdata.zip Jan 4th 2024, 02:48:23 pm 8.42 MB ZIP file

I changed the file name of each dataset according the month of data it contains.

for example:

202303-divvy-tripdata.zip Apr 6th 2023, 04:38:59 pm 10.27 MB ZIP file

was changed to:

df_April_2023

After downloading the files I imported the month of April into python pandas to take a look at the shape, dtypes, unique values, and nulls of the dataset, which are below:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 426590 entries, 0 to 426589
Data columns (total 13 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------              --------------   -----  
 0   ride_id             426590 non-null  object 
 1   rideable_type       426590 non-null  object 
 2   started_at          426590 non-null  object 
 3   ended_at            426590 non-null  object 
 4   start_station_name  362776 non-null  object 
 5   start_station_id    362776 non-null  object 
 6   end_station_name    357960 non-null  object 
 7   end_station_id      357960 non-null  object 
 8   start_lat           426590 non-null  float64
 9   start_lng           426590 non-null  float64
 10  end_lat             426155 non-null  float64
 11  end_lng             426155 non-null  float64
 12  member_casual       426590 non-null  object 
dtypes: float64(4), object(9)
memory usage: 42.3+ MB
```

#check datatypes

```
df_April_2023.dtypes

ride_id                object
rideable_type          object
started_at             object
ended_at               object
start_station_name     object
start_station_id       object
end_station_name       object
end_station_id         object
start_lat             float64
start_lng             float64
end_lat               float64
end_lng               float64
member_casual          object
dtype: object
```

#checking for unique values in each field.

```
df_April_2023.nunique()

ride_id               426590
rideable_type              3
started_at            368670
ended_at              369541
start_station_name      1069
start_station_id        1032
end_station_name        1071
end_station_id          1037
start_lat             151510
start_lng             149608
end_lat                  958
end_lng                  948
member_casual              2
dtype: int64
```

#checking for nulls in each field.

```
df_April_2023.isnull().sum()

ride_id                   0
rideable_type             0
started_at                0
ended_at                  0
start_station_name    63814
start_station_id      63814
end_station_name      68630
end_station_id        68630
start_lat                 0
start_lng                 0
end_lat                 435
end_lng                 435
member_casual             0
dtype: int64
```

I imported the other 11 months of 2023 data into pandas and created a list using the following statement:

```
df_2023 = [df_January_2023, df_February_2023, df_March_2023, 
           df_April_2023, df_May_2023, df_June_2023, df_July_2023, 
           df_August_2023, df_September_2023, df_October_2023, 
           df_November_2023,df_December_2023]
```

Below is the structure of each file in order from Jan to Dec:

```
for structure in df_2023:
    print(structure.info(verbose = False))
    print("end of csv")


<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 190303 entries, 0 to 190302
Columns: 13 entries, ride_id to member_casual
dtypes: float64(4), object(9)
memory usage: 18.9+ MB
None
end of csv
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 190445 entries, 0 to 190444
Columns: 13 entries, ride_id to member_casual
dtypes: float64(4), object(9)
memory usage: 18.9+ MB
None
end of csv
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 258678 entries, 0 to 258677
Columns: 13 entries, ride_id to member_casual
dtypes: float64(4), object(9)
memory usage: 25.7+ MB
None
end of csv
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 426590 entries, 0 to 426589
Columns: 13 entries, ride_id to member_casual
dtypes: float64(4), object(9)
memory usage: 42.3+ MB
None
end of csv
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 604827 entries, 0 to 604826
Columns: 13 entries, ride_id to member_casual
dtypes: float64(4), object(9)
memory usage: 60.0+ MB
None
end of csv
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 719618 entries, 0 to 719617
Columns: 13 entries, ride_id to member_casual
dtypes: float64(4), object(9)
memory usage: 71.4+ MB
None
end of csv
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 767650 entries, 0 to 767649
Columns: 13 entries, ride_id to member_casual
dtypes: float64(4), object(9)
memory usage: 76.1+ MB
None
end of csv
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 771693 entries, 0 to 771692
Columns: 13 entries, ride_id to member_casual
dtypes: float64(4), object(9)
memory usage: 76.5+ MB
None
end of csv
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 666371 entries, 0 to 666370
Columns: 13 entries, ride_id to member_casual
dtypes: float64(4), object(9)
memory usage: 66.1+ MB
None
end of csv
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 537113 entries, 0 to 537112
Columns: 13 entries, ride_id to member_casual
dtypes: float64(4), object(9)
memory usage: 53.3+ MB
None
end of csv
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 362518 entries, 0 to 362517
Columns: 13 entries, ride_id to member_casual
dtypes: float64(4), object(9)
memory usage: 36.0+ MB
None
end of csv
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 224073 entries, 0 to 224072
Columns: 13 entries, ride_id to member_casual
dtypes: float64(4), object(9)
memory usage: 22.2+ MB
None
end of csv
```

If you add the number of entries for each individual dataset you get a total of:

5,719,879 rows of data

Here is where I began to have issues.  After looking at the shape and structure of each individual dataset, I saw that all columns were the same in each, and datatypes were alike as well.

I concatenated all the datasets to make it easier when cleaning and manipulating the data.

statement used to concatenate:

```
df_2023_rides = pd.concat([df_January_2023, df_February_2023, 
                df_March_2023, df_April_2023, df_May_2023, 
                df_June_2023, df_July_2023, df_September_2023,
                df_October_2023, df_November_2023, df_December_2023], 
                axis = 0)
```

The result of the concatenation of all 12 datasets produces:

4,948,186 rows and 13 columns.

This means that during concatenation I lost 771,693 rows of data.

I  do not know what causes the loss of data.  I don't know if I am missing something or wrote the concat statement incorrectly?

I have tried to include all the information that is necessary to reproduce the same results, as I did not do so, initially, when posting this issue.

Comment: How did you get that 4,948,186 number?  What was the statement you used?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome. Please edit your post so as to share all [code, data and error tracebacks as **text, not images**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
To share dataframes: output of `print(df)` or `print(df.to_dict())`.

Comment: [mre] needed. The provided picture of a fragment of the output is of little help, unfortunately. Please come up with a smaller dataset that reproduces your problem, and post it here. Input, output. Isoalting lines that disppear might point you to the answer.

Comment: I have added more code and general information to help with producing the same results.

Comment: @ScottBoston Im fairly new at using stack so I'm not sure how to add code and links to this but I added what I could.  Is it helpful to try and reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Joe, I failed to duplicate your issue with your given dataset.

```
import pandas as pd

l = []
for i in range(1,13):
    l.append(pd.read_csv(f'Downloads/data/2023{i:0>2}-divvy-tripdata.csv'))

total_lines = 0
for df in l:
    print(df.shape)
    total_lines += df.shape[0]
print(f'{total_lines=}')

print(pd.concat(l, axis=0).shape)
```

Output:

```
(190301, 13)
(190445, 13)
(258678, 13)
(426590, 13)
(604827, 13)
(719618, 13)
(767650, 13)
(771693, 13)
(666371, 13)
(537113, 13)
(362518, 13)
(224073, 13)
total_lines=5719877

(5719877, 13)
```

The sum of the individual dataframes' row count equals to the pd.concat'ed dataframe's row count.